# How do I scale a rigged object?

Tags: mesh, objects, rigging

I would like to scale this pair of hands:
[image]

But when I try to do so,this happens:
[image]
The fingers don't scale,I think this has something to do with the bones,(forgive my ignorance,it is all morning that I search for an answer). It would be also fine if I could just scale the posed model,It has already got the pose that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your whole model, it is hard to say, but here is a solution to try... Here is my 'hand' rig:

[image: example hand rig]

Now add a new bone and parent all of the bones to it.

[image: add bone to rig]

Now select the parent bone and scale it.  All of the children bones and their meshes will scale with the parent.

It is possible you have a break in your child/parent relationship in your model? But in general all children bones scale with their parent and, if you do not have a parent bone, you can add one for this purpose.

Comment: Thank You for your answer,I think that would have solved the issue,in the end I decided to simply scale the tree instead.